# How to keep List in client side?

Tags: gwt

I want to keep my list GWT side after fetch it from service side.For example i have button A and when i press, it bring me the list of patient names which start with 'A'. So; I don't want to fetch names from service side all the time. I want to take them for once and store in the cilent side. What am I suppose to do about it? Do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch them all at once at the beginning, and save them on a list and keep a reference of that list across the aplication (where you need it). Then every time you want to see more, just use that list and show the ones you wish to view. But keep in mind that if you have a lot of information on the server side, it might very well be better fetch just a few at the time, otherwise it might take a lot of time to get the bulk list at once.

Answer (score 0):

At beginning fetch all list name and stored them. From this it will not provide u latest or frequented name list. so u can use gwt event service in gwt. I don't know the requirement but u can track like if new patient is added then it will fire the event from server to client and try to add that user also in that list.

Refer link:

http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/